# How to disable warnings and debug output on linux terminal in Qt

Tags: linux, qt

I created a GUI app and it executes some Linux commands and there are some standard output or errors, which are shown when I run my app from terminal in Linux. I run it from terminal because I need root access to execute commands.
but I want to disable showing them.

I tried `CONFIG  += qt warn_off release` but it disabled showing warnings and other text outputs when I run my app from Qt Creator,still there is outputs and warnings when I run it from background terminal.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`warn_off:` The compiler should output as **few warnings** as possible. CONFIG document [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config)

Comment: No, I want to disable showing command output in background terminal, during my app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your .pro file to get rid of Qt debug messages and warnings

```
DEFINES     += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT
```

For linux, unix you can suppress output of any command by using following syntax:

```
command >/dev/null
```

Comment: Nothing happened! for example when the app run `ping 8.8.8.8` some warnings and outputs are shown in background terminal.

Comment: Ok, I understand finally. What you need is not suppressing Qt messages. You need to redirect your output to  /dev/null for Linux?